# asp.net mvc routes over https ssl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, https, routes

I have a website that uses Routes to do some URL rewriting.  Note, I am not using MVC..just the Routes that make MVC famous :P

Anyways the site works completely well...and all is well
I enabled SSL on the entire site and accessing the site in https, I can get static files..I can access the aspx files directly...but the Routes no longer work.

Anyone have this issue?  Do the routes need to be specifically configured for SSL?

Answer (score 3):

**Adding HTTPS/SSL support to ASP.NET MVC routing**
http://blog.codeville.net/2008/08/05/adding-httpsssl-support-to-aspnet-mvc-routing/

See also http://forums.asp.net/p/1260198/2358380.aspx

Comment: any recent updates to this? have recent versions of MVC improved this? Can anyone comment on the availability of any 3rd party products that make this easier?